# Remote Debugging in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, remote-debugging

I am trying to do Remote debugging using Visual Studio 2017

I downloaded the [Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#remote-tools-for-visual-studio-2017) and installed it in the remote server. In the remote server firewall, I configured to allow Inbound & outbound for `msvsmon`. I also allowed inbound for

```
135, 139, 445 TCP  

137, 138,500, 4500 UDP
```

In my machine I configured Firewall to allow Inbound and outbound for Visual Studio 2017

In the visual studio, attach to process, I tried the below

[image]

I also tried using default connection type, but it is not able to connect to the remote machine. What am I missing?

I am adding few more details

the remote machine is running Windows Server 2012 R2
My machine is running on Windows 10, I am using Visual studio 2017

This is the error message that I am getting

[image]

I am running the msvsmon as administrator in the remote machine

In the server msvsmon is showing the `server name:port Number`, but in the visual studio I am connecting using its `ip:port number`. Hope that is ok

[image]

Comment: What is the remote machine?  It's been a while but I remote from VS to a Raspberry with Windows 10 on it and there was a setting on the Raspberry that had to be configured in Windows in order for it to work.  I'd have to dig but if you give a few more details about the remote device I may be able to help.

Comment: Thanks Micheal, the remote machine is a Windows 2012 Server R2 
I have updated the question with this detail now

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: Is `msvsmon` actually running on the server?

Comment: Yes its running on the server
I have updated the question with error message now, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Can you telnet <host> <port> to the remote address?

Comment: No, it said `Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed`  I tried `telnet ipaddress:4022`

Answer (score 2):

- Install from : https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#remote-tools-for-visual-studio-2017 to the remote machine (Be sure of your source and the version of your VS)
- Check if "Visual Studio Remote Debugger" and "Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor" are allowed
- Don't forget to Run it it's called "Remote Debugger"
- And your exe
- From your solution : Debug/Attach to Process...
- Default : yourip:4022
- Select your process then Attach

Comment: If you read the question properly, the poster obviously already went through these steps so this does not help at all.

Comment: @LaurentGiroud Often when something isn't working it's about missing a step or not doing it in the right order

Answer (score 2):

Change Connection type  to **Remote (no authentication)**
[image]

.

Change msvsmon.exe option to **No Authentication**

[image]